# How to use two interfaces as argument using generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm trying to wrapp two interfaces in one to not have to rewrite each method using each interface. I searched a lot but I don't know how can I do this:

```
class ApplyFilter
{

  public static File[] filter (File directory, FileFilterORFilenameFilter filterWrapper)
  {
    return directory.listenFiles(filterWrapper);
  }

}
```

I tried it creating a class that implements both interfaces but then I need to cast the variable. I also tried using java generics using a class like this:

```
public class CustomFilter<T>
{

  /*  Where we store our filter  */
  private T filter = null;

  /*  The method to return it  */
  public T getFilter ()
  {
    return filter;
  }

  /*  The constructor to define the filter  */
  public CustomFilter (T filt)
  {
    if ( !(filt instanceof FileFilter) || !(filt instanceof FilenameFilter) ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The argument must be an instance of FilenameFilter or a FileFilter.");
    this.filter = filt;
  }

}
```

Then I used it like this and it worked:

```
class test
{

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    CustomFilter<FileFilter> onlyShowFolders = new CustomFolder<FileFilter>(new FileFilter ()
    {
      @Override
      public boolean accept (File file)
      {
        return file.isDirectory();
      }
    });

    File root = new File("/");
    for (File folder : root.listFiles(onlyShowFolders.getFilter()))
    {
      System.out.print(folder.toPath());
    }
  }

}
```

But when I use it in the ApplyFilter class it doesn't work.

```
class ApplyFilter
{

  /*  DOESN'T WORK :(  */
  public static File[] filter (File directory, CustomFilter filterWrapper)
  {
    return directory.listenFiles(filterWrapper.getFilter());
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does it give compilation error or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because you omit the most important part for the compiler so that it compile:

```
  public static File[] filter (File directory, CustomFilter filterWrapper)
  {
    return directory.listenFiles(filterWrapper.getFilter());
  }
```

The actual type representation is:

```
  public static File[] filter (File directory, CustomFilter<Object> filterWrapper)
  {
    return directory.listenFiles(filterWrapper.getFilter());
  }
```

And then, it looks for a method `listenFiles` taking an `Object` as single parameter.

Beside, `FilenameFilter` and `FileFilter` does not have a common ancestor, and you can't restrict the type of T, like this:

```
public class CustomFilter<T extends FileFilter>
{

  /*  Where we store our filter  */
  private T filter = null;

  /*  The method to return it  */
  public T getFilter () {
    return filter;
  }

  /*  The constructor to define the filter  */
  public CustomFilter (T filt) {
    this.filter = Objects.requireNonNull(filt, "filt");
  }
}
```

If you are sure you always use the `FileFilter`, you should probably don't use your `CustomFilter` and stick with `FileFilter` unless you know you will add more functionalities. But in that case, have `CustomFilter` implements `FileFilter`.

Comment: So there is no solution to implement both? I tried using `CustomFilter<T extends FileFilter & FilenameFilter>` but in `listenFiles(filter.getfilter())` I need to cast the returned value. I think the only solution is to hardcode all methods.

Comment: Without a "clear" name, like `getFilenameFilter()` returning a `FilenameFilter`, or `getFileFilter()` returning a `FileFilter`, no. You can however adapt `FilenameFilter` to `FileFilter`, since it is basically the same as calling `FileFilter::accept` with `new File(dir, name)` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like what the java library itself does with `File.listFiles` i.e. two functions with same name and different argument type.

```
class ApplyFilter {

    public static File[] filter(File directory, FileFilter filter) {
        return directory.listFiles(filter);
    }

    public static File[] filter(File directory, FilenameFilter filter) {
        return directory.listFiles(filter);
    }

}
```

---

Example holder class, *see comments*

```
public class FilterHolder {
    private FileFilter fileFilter;
    private FilenameFilter filenameFilter;

    public FilterHolder(FileFilter fileFilter) {
        this.fileFilter = fileFilter;
    }

    public FilterHolder(FilenameFilter filenameFilter) {
        this.filenameFilter = filenameFilter;
    }

    public FileFilter getFileFilter() {
        return fileFilter;
    }

    public FilenameFilter getFilenameFilter() {
        return filenameFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what I was trying to do but it seems it's the only way to do it. I don't like harcoding all the methods because the number of methods will be multiplied x 2.

Comment: If you have to duplicate all your methods, there probably is a problem somewhere. You can have a class that hold your filters (see edited answer), and move that along your functions as long as possible. But when you want to actually use the filter, you'll have to have a case for each type.